# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1): Something got wrong during R installation

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I just wanted to install R via CRAN, but something got wrong completely.
What ever I try, I cannot install, remove, or reinstall any packages.
I though dpkg is broken, but my attempt of reinstalling dpkg had failed.

Here's my code and error message.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]         
Hit:3 http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/ InRelease         
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/createsc/3beol/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
Hit:5 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                 
Hit:6 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease               
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
Fetched 109 kB in 5s (19.3 kB/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

sudo apt upgrade
Setting up php7.2-common (7.2.34-10+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.2-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up php5.6-common (5.6.40-40+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
dpkg: error processing package php5.6-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.29) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up nfs-common (1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package nfs-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 (1.9.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5.6:
 php5.6 depends on php5.6-common; however:
  Package php5.6-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up r-base-core (4.0.3-1.1604.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package r-base-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of r-cran-class:
 r-cran-class depends on r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.1604.1); however:
  Package r-base-core is not configured yet.
 r-cran-class depends on r-api-4.0; however:
  Package r-api-4.0 is not installed.
  Package r-base-core which provides r-api-4.0 is not configured yet.
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package php5.6-curl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5.6-opcache:
 php5.6-opcache depends on php5.6-common (= 5.6.40-40+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php5.6-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5.6-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.2-common
 php5.6-common
 grub-pc
 nfs-common
 php5.6
 r-base-core
 r-cran-class
 samba-common
 r-cran-kernsmooth
 r-cran-nnet
 nfs-kernel-server
 r-base-dev
 autofs
 php5.6-readline
 php7.2-readline
 php7.2
 r-cran-mgcv
 php7.2-cli
 r-cran-rpart
 r-base-html
 r-cran-spatial
 php5.6-xml
 unattended-upgrades
 php5.6-cli
 php8.0-common
 r-base
 php5.6-mbstring
 php7.2-json
 r-cran-mass
 r-cran-survival
 samba
 php7.0-common
 libapache2-mod-php5.6
 libapache2-mod-php7.2
 php7.0-xml
 samba-common-bin
 php7.0-intl
 rsyslog
 r-cran-cluster
 php7.2-opcache
 php7.0-mysql
 r-cran-boot
 php7.0-ldap
 r-recommended
 php7.0-readline
 autofs5
 php7.0-opcache
 r-cran-codetools
 r-cran-matrix
 php5.6-curl
 php5.6-opcache
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

I'd already tried this:

```
sudo reboot # Nothing happened

sudo dpkg --configure -a # Nothing happened
sudo apt-get autoclean # Nothing happened
sudo apt-get autoremove -f # Same error

sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg # Same error
sudo apt-get install php7.1-common # Same error
sudo apt purge php7.1-common # Same error
sudo apt --fix-broken install # Same error
```

Now I don't know what to do.
Is there any new idea to recommend? Please

- EDIT

1. Review my /var/log/apt/history :
   This is my latest successful installation before this error occurred.

   ```
    Start-Date: 2020-09-18  10:55:29
    Commandline: apt-get install dos2unix
    Install: dos2unix:amd64 (6.0.4-1)
    End-Date: 2020-09-18  10:55:30
   ```

Then the problematic history was this

```
    Start-Date: 2021-02-09  15:21:44
    Commandline: apt-get upgrade
    Upgrade: ca-certificates-java:amd64 (20160321, 20160321ubuntu1), libpam0g:amd64 (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2, 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.3), debconf:amd64 (1.5.58ubuntu1, 
    ...(lots of lines)...
    1.12.0-1~ubuntu16.04.3), libslang2:amd64 (2.3.0-2ubuntu1, 2.3.0-2ubuntu1.1)
    Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    End-Date: 2021-02-09  15:22:00
```

++ EDIT
From the term.log,
Errors were encountered while processing:

```
php7.1-common
 php5.6-common
 grub-pc
 nfs-common
 php5.6
 r-base-core
 gdm3
 r-cran-class
 php7.1-mbstring
 samba-common
 r-cran-nnet
 nfs-kernel-server
 autofs
 php7.1-xml
 php5.6-readline
 r-cran-rpart
 r-cran-spatial
 php5.6-xml
 unattended-upgrades
 php5.6-cli
 php5.6-mbstring
 r-cran-mass
 samba
 libapache2-mod-php5.6
 samba-common-bin
 rsyslog
 r-cran-cluster
 r-recommended
 autofs5
 r-cran-codetools
 r-cran-matrix
 php5.6-curl
 php5.6-opcache
 php5.6-mysql
 php5.6-json
 r-cran-nlme
 r-cran-foreign
```

So, I removed all of them and reinstalled.
It seems to be working now (at least for now)

However, I got so many [dpkg: warning] lists like this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package r-base.
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-sil-abyssinica' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libatk-adaptor:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'x11proto-fonts-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tigr-glimmer' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxkbfile1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

Comment: @user535733 I just edited my question. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Getting there. Look at that 2021-02-09 transaction in /var/log/apt/term.log. We need to see that entire section. The summary at the end is contains too little information. We need to see exactly which package install failed and why. Details like the package names and versions matter.

Comment: @user535733 new edit just posted! Thanks for your attention

Comment: Use the Search box at the top of the page for your new question.